# WowSlider cant read image title from resx file completely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slider, resx, wowslider

I'm using WowSlider(http://wowslider.com/) image slider for my website (ASP.net MVC).
When I use simple text in Img title it shows the title correctly

```
<img src="~/Content/data1/images/01_____.jpg" 
              title="my image title" alt="my image title" id="wows1_0" />
```

but when I want to get the title from my resource file (.resx) it just read the first word!

```
<img src="~/Content/data1/images/01_____.jpg" 
                  title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg01 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg01 id="wows1_0" />
```

What should I do to make it read the complete title?

my complete index code is as bellow:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <!-- Start Slider HEAD section --> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/engine1/style.css" 
/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End Slider HEAD section -->
<link href="~/Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Start Slider BODY section -->
<div id="wowslider-container1">
<div class="ws_images">
    <ul>
        <li ><img src="~/Content/data1/images/01_____.jpg" 
                  title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg01 
alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg01 id="wows1_0" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/02_________.jpg" 
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg02  
alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg02  id="wows1_1" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/03______.jpg" 
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg03  
alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg03 id="wows1_2" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/04______.jpg"  
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg04  
 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg04 id="wows1_3" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/05____.jpg"  
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg05  
 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg05 id="wows1_4" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/06_______.jpg"  
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg06  
alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg06 id="wows1_5" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/07_____.jpg" 
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg07  
alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg07 id="wows1_6" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/08_______.jpg"  
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg08  
 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg08 id="wows1_7" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/09_____.jpg" 
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg09  
 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg09 id="wows1_8" /></li>
        <li><img src="~/Content/data1/images/10_____.jpg"  
                 title=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg10  
 alt=@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg10 id="wows1_9" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/engine1/wowslider.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/engine1/script.js"></script>
<!-- End Slider BODY section -->
```

Comment: Did you inspect the generated html? You need to use `title="@Resources.ResName"` instead of `title=@Resources.ResName`. Notice the quotes. Something like this would have been easily resolved if you had tried to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around your `title` attribute value if it has spaces in it, else the value will just be the first word.

`title="@Resources.HomeIndexRes.SliderImg01"`

Comment: Thanks . I thought it doesn't need the quoutes anymore as it is code not text :)